# How to show total amount on woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i try create shortcode this :

```
function my_custom_shortcode ( $attr ){

    global $woocommerce;  
    $woocommerce->cart->total;
}
add_shortcode ('totalcart','my_custom_shortcode');
```

to show total amount on the content pages but not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You forget about return.

```
return $woocommerce->cart->total;
```